# VBA to paste data on next available row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having an issue with the pasting portion of my code. The code filters and copies data from a Master Workbook then creates a new workbook and paste that copied data in the new workbook, the problem I am having is that the data that is pasting is over lapping each other when it should paste the newly copied data on the next available row.

Here's the code I have:

```
Set r2 = NewWB.Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        r2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
        r2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
        r2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        r2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        r2.Offset(, 14).Resize(r.Rows.count).Value = ws.name
```

Comment: Does the pasted data *always* have a value in ColA ?  If it doesn't then this approach is not going to work reliably.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't always have a value. I changed the code to a column that will always have a value.

Answer (score 0):

```
With Sheets("sheet name")

  rw = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

  .Range("A" & rw).Value = variable1
  .Range("B" & rw).Value = variable2

End With
```